# What is the point in returning values?

Tags: c++

I'm fairly new when it comes to C++ so bear with me. When learning about return values in functions, I was told that the proper way to write pure functions is to return a value every time. I attempted this in a small function that checks the user's age and returns whether or not they're an adult. The issue here, at least for me, is understanding the proper utilization of these return values. For example, in this code snippet here I'm returning whether or not they are an adult given their age in years.

**main.h**

```
#pragma once
#define LOG(x) std::cout << x
#define LOGCIN(x) std::cin >> x

bool check_age(int age) {
    if (age >= 18)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "main.h"

bool check_age(int age);

int main() {
    int age;
    LOG("Enter your current age in years: ");
    LOGCIN(age);
    bool adult = check_age(age);
    if (adult == true) {
        LOG("You are an adult!");
    } else {
        LOG("You are not an adult!");
    }
}
```

However, when I rewrote this code without using return values, I got this.

**main.h**

```
#pragma once
#define LOG(x) std::cout << x
#define LOGCIN(x) std::cin >> x

void check_age(int age) {
    if (age >= 18)
        LOG("You are an adult!");
    else
        LOG("You are not an adult!");
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "main.h"

void check_age(int age);

int main() {
    int age;
    LOG("Enter your current age in years: ");
    LOGCIN(age);
    check_age(age);
}
```

As you can see, the latter code choices is simpler and more compact. If code requires more lines and takes longer to write with return values, then what's even the point in using them?

Comment: In this case you also won't require the function `check_age` and the code for the function should be put directly in the `main` function. This will make your code more shorter. Also the macros should be removed and expanded for shorter and clearer code.

Comment: Also note that writing implementation of normal (not inline, not templated) function in headers like this example is bad because it may lead to multiple definition error.

Comment: Perhaps in another part of the program you'd need to print "OK, I will sell you liquor" for an adult, and "No, I won't sell you liquor" for non-adult. With the first variant, you could do that. But if you hard-code the specific text into `check_age`, you won't be able to reuse it this way. And if a function can't be reused, there's little point in breaking the code out into a function to begin with.

Comment: Well, in this trivial example, where the function is extremely simple and is only used once, I agree there's not much point in having `check_age` be a function. Often people will write programs that are more complicated than this, however.

Comment: It may be still useful as design unit if code is complex. Essentially "those action are done here". And reuse of code may cross boundaries of single program.

Comment: Food for thought: `bool check_age(int age) { return age >= 18; }`

Comment: Small/trivial test programs - as in this question - rarely provide useful demonstrations on when to use particular language features.  It is always possible to find a small example that demonstrates that some language feature gives little benefit over alternatives. As programs get larger, it is easier to find cases that demonstrate a particular language feature is useful BUT it is also easy to find other cases where that same language language is less useful.  This is why skilled programmer don't assume "X is not useful here, so it is never useful" or "Y is useful here, so it is always useful"

Comment: *"the latter code choices is simpler and more compact"* -- that is largely because of your coding style. When I adapted your code to my coding style, both were the same length (eight total lines in the bodies of the two functions -- or five total lines if I accept awkward syntax while still using your macros). My point is that you should not conclude that one option **requires** more lines just because **your** version uses more lines. No matter how clever you get, there is always a chance that someone else will see something you missed.

Comment: Unrelated: `#define LOGCIN(x) std::cin >> x` seems poorly named as it has nothing to do with logging.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 2):

Often the purpose of a function is not just to log something to `cout` but instead make a decision based on some parameters, or return a value so it can be used flexibly. An example of this would be in binary search:

```
while(l <= r) {
    int mid = (l+r)>>1;
    if(check(/* parameters */)) {
        //update answer
        r = mid+1;
    } else l = mid-1;
}
```

Of course, you could make your function edit a global variable and make decisions based off of that; but it will make the code more verbose:

```
while(l <= r) {
    int mid = (l+r)>>1;
    check(/* parameters */);
    if(ok /* global variable*/) {
        //update answer
        r = mid+1;
    } else l = mid-1;
}
```

As an additional example, it is a lot easier to write (and read):

```
round(a)+ceil(b)
```

than have these functions update global variables.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine the function is provided by someone else.
In that case, we may not be able to know its implementation.
How does our program know whether the function succeeds or not?

Besides, sometimes we want to know some information from a function. I think that's why return values are used.

Comment: One could use the standard functions as examples. Why do they return anything?

Answer (score 0):

Returning a value from the function serves an important purpose - it allows you to separate the two concepts of "determine whether this person is an adult" and "print some stuff about this person".

You could imagine tons of scenarios where the program would need to know if someone was an adult *without* printing it to console - such as allowing them to buy alcohol, register for college, etc etc etc.

And you could also imagine that if you knew someone was an adult, there might be a ton of different ways you'd like to print that (imagine other languages, or rendering it on a webpage, or etc etc).

So by returning the value, you enable this separation of concepts which makes your code much more flexible in the future.

Maybe you don't need that for a toy example, but that's sorta beside the point when you're asking a broad design question like this.